# Validación campos select en jquery

Tags: html, jquery, validación, select, jquery-validate

tengo múltiples campos de selección en el formulario, estos campos se agregan de forma dinámica, pueden haber desde 2 hasta 4, lo que busco es un método para validar todos los campos select por medio de jquery, por el momento tengo un código que si bien funciona al detectar los campos vacíos, el demás código me sigue ejecutando y lo que quiero es que el código pare hasta que todos campos estén validados. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```js
$('.slt_d').change(function(e){

 $('.slt_d').find("option:selected").each(function(){

  if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {

   alert('falta un campo');
  
       
  }


 })
  
  //debe ejecutarse el otro codigo si todos los campos estan completos;
  
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="slt_d">

 <option value="">Seleccione un dato</option> 
 <option value="1">Dato 1</option>
  <option value="2">Dato 2</option>

</select>

<select class="slt_d">

 <option value="">Seleccione un dato</option> 
 <option value="a">Dato A</option>
  <option value="b">Dato B</option>

</select>

//demas select
```

Answer (score 4):

Podrías simplemente crear una variable para saber si existen campos sin completar, por ejemplo:

1. Inicialmente la variable `incompletos`, esta en `false`
2. Si detectamos un `select` sin completar, modificamos el valor de la variable `incompletos` a `true`.
3. Luego para evitar que continue solo basta con comprobar el valor de `incompletos` y hacer un `return;`

Demo

```js
$('.slt_d').change(function(e) {

  var incompletos = false; // AQUI inicializamos la variable
  $('.slt_d').find("option:selected").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
      alert('falta un campo');
      incompletos = true; // AQUI modificamos la variable
    }
  });

  console.log('Hay incompletos: ', incompletos);
  if (incompletos) {// AQUI controlamos la variable
    return;
  }

  //debe ejecutarse el otro codigo si todos los campos estan completos;
  console.log('Éxito!');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="slt_d">
  <option value="">Seleccione un dato</option> 
  <option value="1">Dato 1</option>
  <option value="2">Dato 2</option>
</select>
<select class="slt_d">
  <option value="">Seleccione un dato</option> 
  <option value="a">Dato A</option>
  <option value="b">Dato B</option>
</select> //demas select
```

Comment: Yo añadiría también un `return false;` cuando encuentra el primer campo vacío para evitar que siga comprobando el resto de campos. Así se evita que muestre un mensaje por cada campo vacío.

Comment: Es una buena idea, siempre y cuando no se modifiquen estilos de los incompletos, o se quiera saber cuantos son los incompletos (o alguna otra cosa). Vale recordar que esto es un ejemplo y no un escenario real.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió bastante.

Comment: Hola estoy empleando el script pero no me válida el último select, como que no lo reconoce

Comment: @YtaloDueñas hola, podrías crear un ejemplo [mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?